# What is the purpose of the dice roll at level up?

Tags: blood-bowl-legendary-edition

When a player levels up in campaign mode, there is a dice roll (2d6) before you are allowed to choose skills and/or pick an attribute to increase.  What is the purpose of that dice roll?  What happens if I roll double 1s or double 6s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each skill is in one of five categories: Mutation, Strenght, General, Agility or Passing.
All of these categories are not available for every player type. And some may be accessable only if you roll **any double** (double 1s, double 2s, etc.) These go by player types, not team races, so these may vary within your players.
You'll see under each category either

- Normal (always accessable)
- Double (accesasble on doubles)
- No (never accessable)

Also, if the total of the roll is high enough, you can in stead choose to raise one of the players attributes as follows

- 10 or higher: Raise MA by 1
- 11 or higher: Raise AG by 1
- 12 (double 6s): Raise ST by 1

What ever the roll, you can only choose either one skill to gain or one attribute to raise.

For more information, see the [Living Rulebook](http://www.bloodbowlonline.com/LivingRulebook4-rev.pdf) (page 40 deals with these rolls). The game follows these rules pretty faitfully, with some exceptions and Blitz mode spesific additions.

Comment: I've never played the board game, but so far the computer game is fascinating!

Comment: @yx For most part, the game does its best to hide most of the rules and calculations behind its user interface (and this is a good thing). But ever so often you do find yourself wondering "Why does it work like that?" or "Why do I need a perfect roll for that pass/tackle/catch?". For those situations, I find myself going to the board game rulebook for explanations. It does that a lot better than the game ever does.

Comment: you hit the nail right on the head.  That rulebook will come in handy

Comment: Also want to add that on 
10: +1MA or +1AV